# T-SQL: Get the list of hours between two datetime columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

RAW DATA

table name: guest

| guest_id | guest_name | arrival | departure |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-31 13:00:15 | 2022-01-31 17:00:12 |
| 2 | Mary | 2022-02-01 12:09:03 | 2022-02-01 14:00:03 |

EXPECTED RESULTS

| guest_id | guest_name | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-31 13:00:00 |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-31 14:00:00 |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-31 15:00:00 |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-31 16:00:00 |
| 1 | John | 2022-01-31 17:00:00 |
| 2 | Mary | 2022-02-01 12:00:00 |
| 2 | Mary | 2022-02-01 13:00:00 |
| 2 | Mary | 2022-02-01 14:00:00 |

This is my base query

```
select guest_id, guest_name, arrival, departure from guest
where guest_name in ('John', 'Mary')
```

Recursive CTE is fine but not preferred.

Comment: @Dai: Please read the question.

Comment: T-sql please tag SQL-server

Comment: If you want to avoid a recursive CTE, then I'd use a tally table or tally function like GetNums . It comes in handy quite often for stuff like this or generating dummy data: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/getnumsAB?msclkid=c48fde98ab1d11ec8ff55d8ea9d4e026

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    t1.begin_date, 
    t1.end_date, 
    DATEDIFF(hour, begin_date, end_date) as diff_dates 
from (
    select
        convert(datetime, '2022-01-31 13:00:15') as begin_date,
        convert(datetime, '2022-01-31 17:00:12') as end_date
) t1
```